# Deploy AngularJS app on tomcat apache server

Tags: angularjs, apache, tomcat, gruntjs, yeoman

I have developed an angular project using yeoman, grunt and bower. I wanted to know that the ajax calls and other URLs I am fetching have the address of the backend development server which runs on a local machine.

How do I change all the URLs and addresses which now are located on the production server?
And do I change all the relative Url paths?

I am using grunt build. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I created a war file of the angularjs app. When you deploy the war file on the application server, the IP and port of the server along with the name of the war becomes the base URL of the application. Within the project, all the paths are defined relatively in the state provider with respect to the base URL.